# OpenToke reconnecting delegates are not called when internet is temporarily disabled for subscriber/remote user

Tags: ios, objective-c, opentok

I tried to implement automatic reconnecting of video/audio calls using OpenTok SDK and
I followed this sample project as a reference - https://github.com/opentok/opentok-reconnection/.

The issue we are facing is when the subscriber's(the remote user) internet connectivity is dropped or is turned off we are not getting any below-mentioned call back methods(openTok delegate methods).

**OpenTok Delegate methods for automatic reconnecting**

```
- (void)sessionDidBeginReconnecting:(OTSession *)session
{
    [self showReconnectingAlert];
}

- (void)sessionDidReconnect:(OTSession *)session
{
    [self dismissReconnectingAlert];
}

- (void)sessionDidBeginReconnecting:(OTSession *)session
{
    [self showReconnectingAlert];
}

- (void)subscriberDidDisconnectFromStream:(OTSubscriberKit *)subscriber
{
    [self.reconnectingSpinner startAnimating];
    [self.subscriber.view addSubview:self.streamReconnectingView];
}
```

The publisher(caller) receives no events about the remote connection that gets lost or dropped for a moment.
But on the other hand, when the publisher's internet is dropped or disconnected for a moment all the callback methods are called correctly and we are able to notify the user about network drop by a "Reconnecting UI screen".

**Connecting to Session**

```
- (void)connectVideoSession
{
    OTError *error = nil;
    [session connectWithToken:kTokenID error:&error];// OTSession *session
    if (error) {
        [self showErrorAlert:[error localizedDescription]];
    }
}
```

After the successfull connection we get a call back method

```
- (void)sessionDidConnect:(OTSession*)session
{
    // [ApplicationDelegate removeProgressHUD];
    NSLog(@"sessionDidConnect (%@)", session.sessionId);
    [self doPublish];
}
```

After that, when the subscriber joined the session we will get notified through another call back method

> subscriberDidConnect

Then we are able to subscribe to the session published by end-user (Remote user)

**Version Used**

- OpenTok SDK version - 2.16.3
- Tested on iOS versions - iOS 12.4.5 and iOS 13.3.1

**Success Case**

- Initiated call from iPhone (Publisher)
- Followed this sample app -
  https://github.com/opentok/opentok-reconnection/
- Joined the call from chrome on iMac (Subscriber)
- On the mobile device, I was able to see the stream published by
  Chrome user(iMac) and on the iMAC, I was able to see the stream
  published by the mobile user.
- Then I turned off the internet connection for iPhone (Publisher)
- Then the above-shown methods are getting called and everything is
  working fine.

**Failure Case (Issue we are facing)**

- Initiated call from iPhone (Publisher)
- Followed this sample app -
  https://github.com/opentok/opentok-reconnection/
- Joined the call from chrome on iMac (Subscriber)
- I was able to see the stream on both devices.
- Turned off the internet connection for iMac(Subscriber)
- Then the above-shown methods are not getting called, and we are
  unable to show reconnecting UI for the user.

In this case, all we are seeing is the subscriber's view is getting paused until the internet connection is back for the subscriber

- Why these delegates methods are not working when subscriber(remote
  user) internet is dropped?
- Please advise a way to notify the user that the subscriber is facing a network drop!

Comment: Add your code how you are connecting to session..

Comment: Hi @Daljeet, I Have updated the question, please check.